# Pass path names with spaces to command line

Tags: python-3.x

I am passing the following commandString to a script with paths and params:

"C:/Users/User/Documents/MyVersions/my test scripts/script_to_process.exe" -i "C:/Users/User/Documents/Mapping/Test_Process/file mapping.xlsx" -p "File Mapping" -s "ALL" -tc "V" -sc "O"

Like so:

```
returnCode = os.system(commandString)
```

This works just fine unless I have a directory with spaces in its name. I have, on the advice of other SO questions, added double spaces around the path and still no joy...

What is even more frustrating is that while this path DOES NOT work...

"C:/Users/User/Documents/MyVersions/my test scripts/script_to_process.exe"

This path which also has a space (though it is in a file rather than a directory) DOES...

"C:/Users/User/Documents/Mapping/Test_Process/file mapping.xlsx"

Last bit of info., when I pass this in the path it fails at the 1st space (after my)...

'C:/Users/User/Documents/MyVersions/my' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Do I need to do anything special to handle directory names? Is that it? If not can anyone help me with what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: you can just escape the spaces with `'\ '` instead of plain space `' '`

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly :) - looking into that real quick

Comment: @Kevin He Unless I misunderstood what you are saying, that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Coeur - Done - ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Kevin He for getting me to further research spaces in path names - esp. as it relates to os.system. I finally found the answer at:

[Eli Bendersky's website](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/28/on-spaces-in-the-paths-of-programs-and-files-on-windows)

TL;DR - I have more than one item wrapped in double qoutes and this is no bueno - this is a problem with the Windows cmd.exe processor, not the os.system call.

Eli's solution is to wrap the entire command line call in a double qoute and this worked for me...

Answer (score 3):

In CLI environment, `space` is considered as an argument separator.

To execute command with spaces choose any of the options

1. Escaping space with `\` also known as escape character

   `cmd = "My\ Command\ With\ Space"`
2. Quote the whole command

   `cmd = "'My Command With Space'"`